# Git add fails because commit hook is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: git

I have setup a new local Git repo with LFS support and would like to add my first file.
But my first commit fails with:

```
[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application'
  cmdline: foo-repo\.git\hooks\post-commit
```

It seems it fails to execute the LFS post-commit. Why does Git not understand that it should execute it with the onboard bash shell?

Comment: Im getting the same issue running a pre-commit script through TortoiseGit. Specified the hook through TG's settings but received the same %1... error.